# dropdown values according to rights

Tags: asp.net, authentication, dropdown, admin-rights

There is multiple values in that dropdown ..

```
e.g.
Car
Truck
Bike
Drink
Factory
```

There is another login page  Login.aspx .
Login code

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Label1.BackColor = "F8D8D7";
            loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
            
            Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            Label1.Text = ("Incorrect UserName/Password");
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }
        txt_us.Text = "";
        txt_pwd.Text = "";
        
        
    }
    public bool  loginmethod(string UserName,string Password)
    {
        TrackDataEntities1 td = new TrackDataEntities1();
    
       splogin1_Result sp = td.splogin1(UserName, Password).FirstOrDefault();
       if(sp.Password==txt_pwd.Text)
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }

       

    }
```

Now there is two users .. admin and user . Now i want when admin login then with their id and password then he see some values from this list and when user login then he will see some values from this list for example when admin login then he may able to see only Factory value and when user login then he able to see all values except factory

**UPDATE**

in login.aspx i save username is session

```
Session["UserName"] = txt_us.Text;
```

in form.aspx

Here first i create sp

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spadminlist]
as
select Region from tblReg
where Region in ('Factory')
```

then i add this sp in form.aspx

//this linq query for selecting all values

```
    var list = tea.tblReg.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(x => !x.Region.Any(char.IsDigit)  && (x.Region != ""))
              .GroupBy(x => x.Region)
              .Select(x => new { Region = x.Key, Value = x.Key })
              .ToList();
```

//this is for admin

```
     if (Session["UserName"] = "admin")
        {
            List<spadminlist_Result> admin = tea.spadminlist().ToList();
        }
```

and filling dropdown

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                regiondrop.DataSource = list;
                regiondrop.DataTextField = "Region";
                regiondrop.DataValueField = "Region";
                regiondrop.DataBind();

                Label4.Visible = false;
               


            }
```

but this show error and also how i fill dropdown with admin sp because there is queries

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

how i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**For Dynamic list:**

Get from the backend whether user is admin or normal user.

```
List<string> menuItems = new List<string>();
if(logged_user == "ADMIN")
{
  menuItems.add("item1");
  menuItems.add("item2");
}
else 
{
  menuItems.add("item1");
  menuItems.add("item2");
} 
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "user_name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "user_id";
DropDownList1.DataSource = menuItems;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

**For Static list:**

```
if(logged_user == "ADMIN")
{
  DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("Item1").Enabled = false;

  OR
        DropDownList1.Items[i].Enabled = false;
}
else 
{
  Same process as above.
} 
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "user_name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "user_id";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: but dropdown is another form and login is another form .. there is several values in dropdown which i fetch from database using linq query ..

Comment: when are you showing the dropdown while logging-in or after logging-in? if after logging-in in form.aspx code-behind, you need to write linq query to fetch the user nature (i.e admin or normal) then you can process the dropdownlist.

Comment: but how i call dropdown list control in login page

Comment: ok how i sepcify that when admin login then show these values otherwise when user login then show these values .. how i configure my dropdown linq query or sp login..
ALTER procedure [dbo].[splogin]
UserName nvarchar(50),
Password nvarchar(50)
as
select UserName , Password from tbllogin
where 
UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password

Comment: why you want to call dropdownlist control in login page?.do you have three forms. login.aspx , form.aspx  and webform1.aspx . As per your code after login success redirection happens to webform1.aspx. but dropdown is present in form.aspx. do you need to show that in webform1.aspx?                 .if not three forms used,  In login.aspx you are having username and pwd field and one button. Onclick of button Onsuccess you are redirecting to form.aspx page. In form.aspx codebehind you are going to process the dropdownlist.

Comment: no . there is only two forms.. form.aspx and login.aspx .. dropdown list is in form.aspx and username and password text box are in login.aspx... when i fill name and password values then redirect to form.aspx page..